# Long dropdown menu pulls background on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a menu designed especially for people wanting to show lots of links without it disappearing down beneath the browser.
Instead, once the menu reaches a maximum height it enables users to scroll within it.

Once it reaches this height the menu calls on the javascript to create this "sub menu", however, when doing this is pulls down the background of the menu to the bottom of the internal menu and when I hover away from it the width of the `ul` has expanded.

I've created a fiddle to demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/H3Gb3/

Please use the jQuery 1.6.4 to see it work.

How it looks right there is how I want it to look. If you first hover over the **average menu** this is how I want it to react with the long menus too.
But if you try the first two menus - which exceed the max height and execute the js for a sub menu they distort the whole menu.
I've used a gradient background so you can better understand what is happening.
Also, you can notice that after hover, they don't return to the same place.

I don't know what is causing this. I at first thought it was a z-indez issue but through trial and error have not been able to uncover one.

I've searched on here for a solution and found somebody else who was using this menu and had the same problem I do but no one could offer a resolution.

Can anyone tell me what is exactly happening to distort the menu? Is it a CSS issue?

Comment: I think it's because you are setting the height of the containing `li` which extends the height of the whole container.

Comment: You should provide the code here for posterity.

Comment: Thanks mzedeler, I will add it as an edit.

Comment: Just add --- height:35px; -- to the --- #page-wrap --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Gb3/2/

I changed your code here:

```
 $container
       .css({
           height: maxHeight,
           width: "250px",
           overflow: "hidden"
        })
```

to

```
$container
       .css({
          width: "250px",
        })
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have done the trick for the pulling of the BG. Is there any way around the extended width's post-hover?

Comment: Remove the `width: 250px`

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't try that - I was playing around in the JS for a while. I'll just add a z-index to it so it goes in front of the rest of the menu.

Comment: @user3583173 Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes.